# conditional match on rails rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to write a test on helper method which fetches data from external service based on an id. So there is an uncertainty whether the value will be returned or nil. But if value is returned, id of returned value must be equal to given id. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
expect(record).to be_nil.or expect(record.id).to eq(deal.user_id)
```

however it seems the or condition does not work the way I think. I am new to RoR. Might be missing any obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write ruby code in specs too:

```rb
if record != nil
  expect(record.id).to eq(deal.user_id)
end
```

or combine matchers:

```rb
expect(record).to be_nil.or(eq(deal.user_id))
```

Comment: @Ankit do you have dot(`.`) between `be_nil` and `or`? (otherwise ruby will treat `or` as an low-priority operator, not method call as you need)

Comment: tried with (.) looks like it doesn't short circuit. Like even if 1st case is true, it evaluates remaining conditions too